# Comunication between two classes using Protocols and Delegation in Swift - Not working, see code

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, delegation

I'm practicing Protocols and Delegation to have a better understanding about the pattern but I'm probably doing something wrong because I'm getting an error.

What I'm trying to do is to establish communication between the following two classes using the delegation pattern.

Here is the code:

```
protocol MyDelgate{

    func greeting(message: String)
}
```

Sender Class

```
class DelegateClass{

    var delegate: MyDelgate?

    self.delegate?.greeting(message: "Hello")
}
```

Receiver Class:

```
class Receiver: MyDelgate{

    func greeting(message:String){
        print("\(message)")
    }

}
```

ERROR:

> ERROR at line 14, col 5: expected declaration
>       self.delegate?.greeting(message: "Hello")

See it in IBM Swift SandBox
http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57990af896ff73f744b73c32

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has to be inside a function

Comment: @dan not in the IBM sandbox. You can just write inside the main file.

Comment: @bobek He doesn't want to just write inside the main file though, he's trying to use the delegate pattern so his code needs to be inside his class where it needs to be inside a function.

Comment: @dan I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the object first. Working example: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57990d39f368f28575c3ebe2

```
protocol MyDelgate{

    func greeting(message: String)
}

class Receiver: MyDelgate{

    func greeting(message:String){
        print("\(message)")
    }

}

var delegate: MyDelgate? = Receiver()

delegate?.greeting(message: "Hello")
```

Comment: @ bobek I was thinking more about something like the method used in iOS when you pass data from one viewController to the main viewController using protocols, is this even possible with simple classes, on my case using two classes and a protocol, is this possible. As I said, I don't fully understand the pattern so I may be asking for something crazy. What would be the difference between your code and just `var receiver = Receiver()
receiver.greeting(message:"Hello")`? Thanks a lot!